# How to slug an url using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm building a website with several articles. I'm using Vue Router, and for the moment the urls of my articles look like /article/id, for example : `http://localhost:8080/article/85`.

How can I slug an URL with the article title so it can be `http://localhost:8080/article/the-article-title` for example ?

I have no idea what kind of code should I provide so here is my article route :

```
routes: [
 {
   path: '/article/:id',
   component: require('../components/articlePage.vue').default,
   name: 'article',
   meta: {title: "article"}
  }, 
]
```

Comment: Once user enters `/article/85`, how do you fetch article data and where is it stored?

Comment: It is stored in a Vuex Store, I fetch the data from an API with an action, and I use a mutation to call this from a component

Comment: Do you fetch a single article with provided `id` or load multiple articles? Does your API support querying articles by `slug` or `title`?

Comment: I fetch all the articles and I sort by id if I want to display only one with article/:id ; I think the API supports this

Answer (score 9):

First add a slug in your JSON object if it is not exist in your API or DB

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Jungle Book',
  slug: 'jungle-book',
  showDate: 'Monday',
  showTime: '19:10 - 20:55'
}
```

Change the path in your router index file according to your path and component.
And the path should have ":slug"

```
 {
   path: '/movies/:slug',
   name: 'moviedetail',
   component: MovieDetail
}
```

In the "router-link" add the slug after v-for

```
<router-link :to="'/movies/' + movie.slug">
```

Now get the data from your component

```
 data() {
   return {
      movie: this.$store.state.data,
      movieDetail: []
   }
 },

 methods: {
     getMovie(){
        this.movie.forEach(e => {
           if(e.slug == this.$route.params.slug){
              this.movieDetail = e;
           }
        });
      }
  },

  created() {
     this.getMovie();
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

There are different approaches with increasing level of complexity and aspects taken care of.

So to start - in order to `slug`-ify articles, you have to introduce slugs to the application. Since it is mentioned in comments that all articles are fetched priorly, slugs can be added to each article data before saving them to store with custom function that converts words to kebab-case or one of helper libraries (e.g. [dashify](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/dashify)).

This will make possible to render list of article links using `:slug` as route `param`, instead of `id` and search in store for by `param` before rendering article page. Good thing is that it still possible to keep both options (`slug` and `id`) available by extending logic to search by 2 fields.

Depending on your target - that might be it. But the problem arises in case article title has been changed and user accesses article via externally saved link (shared in social media, indexed by search engines, etc). This defeats [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

In order to keep article accessible, it is a good practice to include `slug` as a required field on the back-end. Slug still can be generated with same approach, but in CMS - before article is stored in the database. In such case it can be double checked, manually edited (as slugs do not always represent full article title because of characters length, special symbols, etc) and be accessible for querying, thus removing hassle of string manipulation from the front-end application.

Also this creates options to configure [301 redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to preserve indexation even after `slug` is changed by saving old slugs. But such problem is out of the scope of the current question, even though is a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Router:

```
{
  path: '/:slug',
  name: 'article',
  component: articlePage
}
```

Component:

use beforeRouteEnter to show the slug

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    console.log(to.params.slug);
}
```

Comment: Hi Felipe Toro, welcome to stackoverflow! Please consider adding an explanation of the code you have provided, or context for why this solution works. Check out this [guide on how to answer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info.