# VueJS Best Approach to Random Slug Based URLs

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component that renders blog posts. It currently just loads a collection of posts and renders them to the UI. This all works great.

Each of these posts has a slug, i.e. `the-best-post-ever`.

I'd like to enable my blog component to be able to read that value (or be passed it) and render that individual post instead of the list.

So visiting the blog would be something like `http://example.com/blog` whereas an individual post would be `http://example.com/blog/the-best-post-ever`.

What's the best way of handling this?

Comment: I guess you are already familiar with https://router.vuejs.org/?

Comment: Indeed. This is how I initially thought to deal with it but I'm still pretty new to Vue so wanted to ensure it makes sense to use this approach. Just after posting this question I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025195/vuejs-best-approach-to-handling-urls

Comment: Seems like the link is referring to this topic. :) But if you don't need SSR, you can use beforeRouteEnter and beforeRouteUpdate guards to fetch data with http request. Should I write you an example?

Comment: is it me or found this "link" <- is the same as this post?

Comment: Oops, this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243924/how-to-slug-an-url-using-vuejs

Comment: @Jammer approach in the above link (ie. using dynamic param, https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) makes sense in the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation guys. Already have a working example using this approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out this is extremely simple.

I updated my router:

```
name: 'blog',
title: 'Blog',
path: '/blog/:slug?',
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "blog" */ './views/Blog.vue'),
meta: {
    isMain: true,
    public: true,  // Allow access to even if not logged in
    requireAdmin: false,
},
```

And now in the Blog component:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.slug);
},
```

I can now ping the slug off to the server API and get this post.

In my Blog component I store this in a local variable:

```
created() {
    this.slug = this.$route.params.slug;
},
```

And pass this onto the actual blog rendering component like this:

```
<BlogReaderComponent category="news" :slug="slug" />
```

The blog reader component can then simply ignore any category variable and render a single post as opposed to a collection of posts.

I switched from `mounted()` to `created()` as in order for this data to be available early enough in the life-cycle so that when the `<BlogReaderComponent` is created this value is properly initialised.